# I am trying to fetch users using Github API, but it says the token is wrong

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I am try to fetch users information using github API

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function UserResults() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_URL}/users`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    const data = response.json();
  };
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

export default UserResults;
```

And here is what I put in my env:

```
REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN="<token>"
REACT_APP_GITHUB_URL = "https://api.github.com"
```

I am sure the token is correctly generated and copied.

But it seems I can't fetch the data due to some "JSON" error as it shows in the console like this.

Can anyone offers any help with this?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to await response.json() and update your header request

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function UserResults() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_URL}/users`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `token ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
  };
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

export default UserResults;
```

Comment: Very helpful, to the point, thx